# Itemwriter method close exception status of batch completed (not failed)

Tags: exception, spring-batch, status, itemwriter

An exception in an `ItemWriter#close` method is not causing the exit status to be marked as **FAILED**. Can you confirm that is the expected behavior ?

According to my understanding, when `ItemWriter#close` method is called, the items **must have been processed successfully**.

We encountered **no errors** during the phase of **reader, processor or writer**.

As as result, the exit status is marked as **COMPLETED**.

In other words, `ItemWriter#close` method is only useful for clean up of resources and does not impact the results of the step.

Do you agree with my explanation ? Can you confirm ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Please be more specific about the issue? Which ItemProcessor implementation are you using? Source code? Which exception are using for the simulation?

Comment: I use the method close of this class, and an ioexception is launched : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractFileItemWriter.java

Comment: What exception exactly? Please add stack trace to the question.

Comment: Thanks, i found explanation in this article : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1726

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ItemWriter#close`, it is rather `ItemStream#close`.

`ItemStream#close` is designed to clean up resources that were used in the step, and nothing more. If an exception is thrown in that method, all the relevant business processing should have been already done at this point so it should not cause a failure of the step.